# Tkinter code not showing button (v:3.6)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my practice from youtube, It's not showing button in window

```
import tkinter as tk
class Window(Frame):
    def _init_ (self, master =None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('GUI')
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        quitButton = Button(self, text = "Quit")
        quitButton.place(x=0, y =.1)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('GUI')
root.geometry()
app = Window(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `_init_` to `__init__`.

Comment: it says that Window(Frame): is not defined.

Comment: Change `Frame` to `tk.Frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `_init_` to `__init__`.
Python constructor syntax has double underscore.

[UNDERSTANDING SELF AND `__INIT__` METHOD IN PYTHON CLASS.](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)

> `__init__` is a reseved method in python classes. It is known as a constructor in object oriented concepts. This method called when an object is created from the class and it allow the class to initialize the attributes of a class.